# Laravel QrCode::wiFi does not accept variables

Tags: php, laravel, variables, qr-code

hi i need to generate wifi qr code from variable from database. i use laravel.

this works good:
`{!! QrCode::wiFi(['ssid' => 'wifiname','password' => 'wifipass','encryption' => 'WPA']); !!}`

I'm trying user setting value:

```
{!! QrCode :: wiFi ($ col); !!}
```

where `$col` has value

```
['ssid' => 'wifiname','password' => 'wifipass','encryption' => 'WPA']
```

and tadabase column type is `text` , i try `varchar(255)` and its same.

`echo $col;` =  `['ssid' => 'wifiname','password' => 'wifipass','encryption' => 'WPA']`

but unfortunately the code always has the values ssid=null, password=null, encryption=null

any idea please? Thank you

Comment: You're using varchar to store an array ? 
The proper solution would be to store your array as JSON in a JSON column and then set arguments using {!! QrCode :: wiFi (json_decode($col)); !!}

Comment: hello thank you for your reply.
I tried in migration `$ table-> json ('qr_data') -> nullable ();`
and stored in the database `{"ssid": "wifiname", "password": "wifipass", "encryption": "WPA"}`

and as you suggested `{!! QrCode :: wiFi (json_decode ($ col)); !!}` in blade view

but i get an error
`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

     `protected function setProperties (array $ arguments)

     {
         $ arguments = $ arguments [0];

         if (isset ($ arguments ['encryption'])) {

             $ this-> encryption = $ arguments ['encryption'];

         }...`

Comment: {!! QrCode :: wiFi (json_decode($col,true)); !!}  instead of  {!! QrCode :: wiFi (json_decode($col)); !!}

Comment: @Octet ou yyyyeees! thanks works good